# Android Studio, change the editor background color (not the whole theme)

Tags: android

The same question was marked as "duplicate" even though it obviously was not a duplicate. At least it should be obvious to anyone who is familiar with configuring an editor. When you want to change the background color, you aren't talking about changing the whole theme, you are talking about changing the background color.

Is there a way to change only the background color in Android Studio editor?

Answer (score 36):

Sorry, but I believe you all have this one wrong. To change the background of the editor goto ***File, Settings, Editor, Colors & Fonts*** and select ***General***. You'll see an item called **"*Default text*"**. On the right of the window you will see a checkbox for *background*. Click in the color window and choose whichever color you prefer. Now the entire editor window will show that color as the background.

Comment: you are right, it is the way to change the background editor color. 
But I think they should consider add to the list an element named something like "Main Background", or similar. 

I spent 20 minutes looking for the right element in order to change the editor background color.

In my opinion "Default text" is not really intuitive. Because you tend think that refer only to the text.

Comment: Can you update your answer for AS 3 or add screen shots? There seem to no such option anymore.

Comment: See the answer from [smail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553582/8209253)

Comment: There is no ***Colors & Fonts*** Editor option in **Windows** AS 3.1.2 . See my Answer.

Answer (score 15):

go to : **Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General**

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer at least on Android Studio 3.1.2 on a Mac.

Answer (score 6):

In Android Studio 3.2.1 Windows (latest version as of today - Nov 2, 2018), go to 
**File > Settings > Editor > Color scheme > General > Text-Default text**.  One can change foreground and background colors using the panel on the right.

One can change the bottom logcat panel colors similarly - go to
**File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Colors > Console** (or **log Console**)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. Open *Settings* (*Preferences* on a Mac) and under IDE Settings expand *Editor*, *Colors & Fonts* and select *General*. You'll see *Background* in a menu on the left side. Click on the checkbox next to it if it's not ticked already and then double click on the square filled with current background color to get the color picker.

Comment: Any idea where the colours for the IDE's outermost borders can be changed? These settings mentioned above only allow the changing of colours within windows (text and background colours).

Answer (score 2):

AndroidStudio 3.3.2

1st step:

[image: global scheme]

2nd step:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 4.1.2 on Mac

**File -> Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Text -> Default Text**

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Update 2023:

Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Colors Scheme > General

Search for Text > Default text and change the background color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the Answers above have correct info for **Windows** Android Studio 3.1.2.

On Mac, apparently this works: go to  **Android Studio** > **Preferences** > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General, but we Windows folk don't have an Android Studio tab or option and **Preferences isn't an option anywhere**.

We have **File** > **Settings** > **Editor**. Here's the screen with the only conceivable next links to click highlighted:

[image]

But here's what I see when I click **General**. I can select this background:

[image]

But I can't live with that.

In **Windows 7, AS 3.1.2** the menu sequence--**File > Settings > Editor > Color scheme > General > Text > Default text**--takes you to a screen where you can set the foreground and background colors via a "color circle" or by typing in your favorite `RRGGBB` code(s).

[image]

I was pleasantly surprised by how an error in an `xml` file showed up (and the current line):

[image]